# Easiest way to insert simple data into an Excel file from .Net

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have an excel file that has ~10 columns and 1-20 rows. I need to insert 1-20 rows with various data elements.

I was wondering if there was a way I could put some tags in the excel file so they could be found and replaced. Something that marks a column as "Name". That way in code I could just say:

`Name[0] = object.name;`

I'm not sure if this exact method is possible, but I really don't need any heavy lifting and I rather not hard code the cell locations as the excel file might change over time.

I will also have to add a hidden 'ID' cell in row. I imagine I can cross that bridge later though.

Comment: What have you tried? MSDN has examples?   You have ADO.NET and automation.   With ADO.NET a named range can be treated like a table.   ADO.NET uses the Jet provider.  ADO.NET requires some structure but it is way easier (in my mind) and does not require Excel.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using ADO.NET is easy to add a row to an Excel Sheet

```
string fileName = @"D:\test.xlsx"; 
string connectionString = String.Format(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" + 
        "Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=0'", fileName); 

using(OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    cn.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] " + 
         "([Column1],[Column2],[Column3],[Column4]) " + 
         "VALUES(@value1, @value2, @value3, @value4)", cn);
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value1", "Key1");
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value2", "Sample1");
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value3", 1);
   cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value4", 9);
   cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The code above assumes that you have a first row with an header with Column1... as column names.
Also, the code use the ACE OleDB provider for Excel 2007 or 2010 instead of Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0.

EDIT: To refer to a Named Range you could change the sql command to this one

```
    OleDbCommand cmd1 = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO [yourNamedRange] " + 
                        "VALUES(@value1, @value2, @value3, @value4)", cn);
```

Alas, I can't find a way to refer to the individual columns.

Comment: Thanks for this response. Do you know if there is an easy way to more intelligently add values? Perhaps using named ranges already existing in the excel file.

Comment: My issue is that there are several rows above the section that I need to edit. Sorry this was not conveyed in my initial post.

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you very much. I had a nightmare googling this problem.

Comment: Is there a faster way to insert rows? Hundreds or thousands is making my website run slow

Answer (score 7):

```
    private Excel.Application app = null;
    private Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
    private Excel.Worksheet worksheet = null;
    private Excel.Range workSheet_range = null;
    private const int FIRTSCOLUMN= 0 //Here const you will use to select good column
    private const int FIRSTROW= 0
    private const int FIRSTSHEET= 1

    app = new Excel.Application();
    app.Visible = true;
    workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
    worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[FIRSTSHEET];
    addData(FIRSTROW,FIRTSCOLUMN,"yourdata");


 public void addData(int row, int col, string data)
    {
        worksheet.Cells[row, col] = data;

    }
```

Comment: For those wondering why this code doesn't work for them, as I was, you need to change FIRTSCOLUMN and FIRSTROW to something other than 0,0.  The top-left cell in an Excel worksheet is 1,1.