# Write to a Workbook that was created in a different function using c#

Tags: c#, excel

I have code that currently creates several different excel files but now I need to modify that to where it is all in one workbook.I have a function that creates the workbook.

```
public void startSavingProcess()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    if (xlApp == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Oops, Excel is not properly installed on this machine.");
    }
    try
    {
        xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        xlApp.Workbooks.Add();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " \t\t" + ex.ToString(), "Error Saving", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

How do I go about calling the workbook that I previously created?

```
create_FileOne()
string newfileName = "File_" + counter + "myFileOne" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yy") + ".xls";
String newfilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + newfileName;
Console.WriteLine(newfilePath);

while (File.Exists(newfilePath))
{
    counter++;
    newfileName = "File_" + counter + " myFileOne" + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yy") + ".xls";
    newfilePath = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + newfileName;
    Console.WriteLine(newfilePath);
}

//xlAPP.Workbooks.Open();
```

Comment: There are a ton of resource out there on how to add and remove data from an excel worksheet using the same methods you are working with. For example, this SO post has two different methods to add data to a worksheet, one with ADO and one similar to how you are currently working with excel. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148111/easiest-way-to-insert-simple-data-into-an-excel-file-from-net

Answer (score 0):

The code below opens an existing workbook...

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

...

Application xlApp = new Application();
Workbook workbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);
```